# Insert dynamic tab names and fields into this formula google sheets

Tags: google-sheets, indexing, tabs, google-sheets-formula

I am struggling with my formula. The formula itself returns the value of the last row of a certain column. Now I would like to work more dynamically. I would like to dynamize the tab names and certain fields. In this case `'SR-SG'` and `$EQ:$EQ` getting these values out of a cell. Any ideas on how I can do that?

```
=index('SR-SG'!$EQ:$EQ;max(row('SR-SG'!$EQ:$EQ)*('SR-SG'!$EQ:$EQ<>"")))
```

Answer (score 0):

in A1 the name of the sheet, in B1 the column (in number, i.e. 26 for column Z)

```
=index(OFFSET(indirect("'"&A1&"'!$A:$A");;B1-1);max(row(OFFSET(indirect("'"&A1&"'!$A:$A");;B1-1))*(OFFSET(indirect("'"&A1&"'!$A:$A");;B1-1)<>"")))
```

or in A1 the name of the sheet, in B1 the column in letter (i.e. Z)

```
=index(indirect("'"&A1&"'!$"&B1&":$"&B1);max(row(indirect("'"&A1&"'!$"&B1&":$"&B1))*(indirect("'"&A1&"'!$"&B1&":$"&B1)<>"")))
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for help, much appreciated. Doesn't work. There is an error message with value. It looks like its expecting a number but receives text...

=index(OFFSET(indirect("'"&E29&"'!$EJ:$EJ");;B1-1);max(row(OFFSET(indirect("'"&E29&"'!$EJ:$EJ");;B1-1))*(OFFSET(indirect("'"&E29&"'!$EJ:$EJ");;B1-1)<>"")))

Comment: You should have given a comment, not an answer. I have updated my answer with a second solution, both works well. Why do you put EJ ? Pls provide a spreadsheet if necessary

Comment: You are a genious!!!!!! THX, now it works! Next time i'll use comments. It was my first time that I raised a question here! ;-)